# I want Apache only to listen to port 80 on the addresses I specify. Can I?

Tags: apache, http, node.js

I have a bunch of domains pointing to one IP address (I have a feeling this will be the main thing stopping this from working) and one of them I would like to point to a node.js server on port 80 instead of having to faff about with proxies in Apache.

I've already removed the virtualhost for *:80 in apache (it warns me of this every time I restart it).

When I ask node to listen to domain.one:80 though (just an example, not what I'm really using), it doesn't work - it tells me the address is in use even though there's no VirtualHost for domain.one:80.

I suspect it's to do with the fact that domain.one and domain.two both point to the same IP, right? If not, what the heck can I do? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Ports are directly tied to an IP address. Each IP address can only have one process listening to a given port. Since your domain names all resolve to the same IP address you cannot have a separate node process for each one listening on port 80.

If you wish to keep this scheme, you'll need to have each node server listen on a different port and configure reverse proxies in Apache as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/201196/apache-port-redirect). You can also consider using [nginx](http://nginx.org/) as it also has this capability (configured slightly differently).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can specify  a servername in the vhost.  Then you can only specify an IP or * in the  tag.  Create a *:80 Vhost and add

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerName domain.one
     DocumentRoot /blah/blah
     ....
 </VirtualHost>
```

to it.  That will filter by the domain name.

Comment: I'm afraid that as I suspected and as RatDaddy pointed out since all the domains point to the same IP this won't solve the problem, but thanks :)